# Grafana tar file download

Tags: grafana

I have been searching web since hours but the only way to get tar file is through `wget` which I cant as my server don't have net access.

I want to download tar file of Grafana, where can I get it to download ?

Comment: I didn't get it. How do you want to download it if you don't have Internet access?

Comment: I will download in my windows machine and using WinSCP upload it to server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just visit the [Grafana download page](https://grafana.com/grafana/download), choose your platform and click on the desired link.

For example: https://dl.grafana.com/oss/release/grafana-7.5.7.linux-amd64.tar.gz